# What is the issue with this trigger (for the right syntax to use near '' )

Tags: mysql, triggers

Please I did this trigger to update table `rating` after each insert when 2 columns (id_prof,id_etud) inserted are already in the table but it gives mi this error

```
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6
```

The trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER Before_Insert_Rate
BEFORE INSERT ON rating
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM rating WHERE id_prof=NEW.id_prof and id_etud = NEW.id_etud)) THEN
    UPDATE `rating` SET `rate` = NEW.rate WHERE `id_prof` = NEW.id_prof and `id_etud` = NEW.id_etud; 
    ELSE INSERT INTO rating VALUES (NEW.idprof,New.rate,New.id_etud);
  END IF
END
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot modify the data in the table the trigger is on; i.e. no UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE on `rating` is allowed in the trigger.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using `ON DUPLICATE KEY` on a query instead of trigger

```
CREATE TABLE `rating` (
  `id_prof` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rate` float NOT NULL,
  `id_etud` int(11) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE (id_prof,id_etud)
)
```

> the query :

```
INSERT INTO rating (id_prof,rate,id_etud) VALUES (1,2,5)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE rate=2
```

Answer (score 0):

You must set the **DELIMITER** before. Change it to:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER Before_Insert_Rate
BEFORE INSERT ON rating
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM rating WHERE id_prof=NEW.id_prof and id_etud = NEW.id_etud)) THEN
    UPDATE `rating` SET `rate` = NEW.rate WHERE `id_prof` = NEW.id_prof and `id_etud` = NEW.id_etud; 
    ELSE INSERT INTO rating VALUES (NEW.idprof,New.rate,New.id_etud);
  END IF
  END; //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

from [the official reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/faqs-triggers.html#faq-mysql-can-triggers-tables).

> A trigger can access both old and new data in its own table. A trigger
>   can also affect other tables, but **it is not permitted to modify a
>   table that is already being used (for reading or writing) by the
>   statement that invoked the function or trigger.**

This means no query on table `X` can INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE from table `X`; it also means that if a trigger on table `X` modifies table `Y`, it will fail for any query using both table `X` and `Y` that "triggers" it.

*Example: `UPDATE x INNER JOIN y ON x.id = y.id SET x.something = 1, y.something = 2` will cause a `BEFORE UPDATE ON x` trigger (that updates, inserts, or deletes from `y`) to fail.*

Comment: so what is the solution ?

Comment: The solution is to take a different approach, a trigger cannot do what you want. You probably want to look into using a `REPLACE INTO` query, or and INSERT query's `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause.

Comment: I tried to use ON DUPLICATE KEY but i have 2 columns must be unique

Comment: i can't have (1,5,3) and (1,2,3)
but i can have (1,5,3) and (4,5,3) or (1,4,6)

Comment: Add a composite unique key on the two fields that must be unique; judging from your trigger, that would be UNIQUE KEY (`id_prof`, `id_etud`).

Comment: I did it but he always considers just the id_etud as unique

Comment: Add current table def (CREATE statement including keys) to your question.

Comment: I solved it with `ON DUPLICATE KEY` the problem was in my CREATE statement ... thank you so much for your help and for time