# Update a different row in same table in before update

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a table with family relationships. One of these relationships is spouse. When a row is inserted or updated (separate triggers), if the ID of a spouse is present, I want to update the ID in the related spouse's record.

IOW, if a row with an ID of 2 is updated and has and spouse_id of 3, I want the row with an ID of 3 to have it's spouse id set to 2.

Here's the schema of the table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gohman_birthdays` (
    `gb_id`         INT(11) UNSIGNED        NOT NULL    AUTO_INCREMENT                  COMMENT 'Primary Key',
    `gb_created`    TIMESTAMP                           DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'   COMMENT 'Timestamp when record was created',
    `gb_modified`   TIMESTAMP                           DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'   COMMENT 'Timestamp when record was last modified',
    `gb_name`       VARCHAR(30)             NULL        DEFAULT ''                      COMMENT 'Full Name',
    `gb_lname`      VARCHAR(30)             NULL        DEFAULT 'Gohman'                COMMENT 'Last Name',
    `gb_maidenname` VARCHAR(30)             NULL        DEFAULT ''                      COMMENT 'Maiden Name',
    `gb_nickname`   VARCHAR(30)             NULL        DEFAULT ''                      COMMENT 'Nick-Name',
    `gb_email`      VARCHAR(100)            NULL        DEFAULT ''                      COMMENT 'Email Address',
    `gb_phone1`     VARCHAR(30)             NULL        DEFAULT ''                      COMMENT '1st Phone',
    `gb_phone2`     VARCHAR(30)             NULL        DEFAULT ''                      COMMENT '2nd Phone',
    `gb_dob`        DATE                    NULL        DEFAULT 1                       COMMENT 'Date Of Birth',
    `gb_dod`        DATE                    NULL        DEFAULT 1                       COMMENT 'Date Of Death',
    `gb_fatherid`   INT(11)                 NULL        DEFAULT NULL                    COMMENT 'FK to father parent ID',
    `gb_motherid`   INT(11)                 NULL        DEFAULT NULL                    COMMENT 'FK to mother parent ID',
    `gb_spouseid`   INT(11)                 NULL        DEFAULT NULL                    COMMENT 'FK to mother parent ID',
    `gb_gender`     TINYINT(1)              NULL        DEFAULT NULL                    COMMENT '1 if male, 0 if female',
    `gb_deceased`   TINYINT(1)              NULL        DEFAULT 0                       COMMENT '0 or 1 flag, 1 if deceased',
    PRIMARY KEY (`gb_id`),
    KEY `idx_gb_nickname` (`gb_nickname`),
    KEY `idx_gb_email` (`gb_email`),
    KEY `idx_gb_name` (`gb_name`),
    KEY `idx_gb_dob` (`gb_dob`),
) 
    ENGINE=MyISAM 
    AUTO_INCREMENT=1 
    DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 
    COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
    COMMENT '';
```

And here's what I have so far for the triggers:

```
-- ==============================================================================================
-- TRIGGER: Update created and modified timestamps on gohman_birthdays
-- ==============================================================================================
DELIMITER |

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `gohman_birthdays_CreatedTS`|
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `gohman_birthdays_ModifiedTS`|

CREATE TRIGGER `gohman_birthdays_CreatedTS` BEFORE INSERT ON `gohman_birthdays`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`gb_created` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    SET NEW.`gb_modified` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
END|

CREATE TRIGGER `gohman_birthdays_ModifiedTS` BEFORE UPDATE ON `gohman_birthdays`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.`gb_modified` = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
    IF NOT NEW.`gb_spouseid` IS NULL THEN
        UPDATE `gohman_birthdays` a
            SET a.`gb_spouseid` = NEW.`gb_id`
            WHERE a.`gb_id` = NEW.`gb_spouseid`;
    END IF
END|

DELIMITER ;
```

Questions:

- Can I update a different row inside a trigger?
- Should it be in a BEFORE UPDATE/INSERT trigger or an AFTER trigger?
- Should it be in a stored procedure instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trigger cannot change the data in any table referenced by the query that initiated the trigger.

It's not the same question, but my more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48234259/4104224) applies.

---

A better solution would be to make a separate table to actually hold the relationships (rather than the several reference fields in the apparently increasingly misnamed "birthdays" table).
This new table would look something like:

```
Person1_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
Person2_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
Relationship_id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
```

Relationship_id would reference a new `Relationships` table that has information on directional terms. 
Examples:

```
1, "Parent", "Child"
2, "Spouse", "Spouse"
3, "Sibling", "Sibling"
4, "Aunt", "Niece"
etc....
```

*... though siblings and aunt-niece relations could be calculated with joins.*

Comment: @uuerdo, thanks for the quick response. I figured I could find sibling and cousins, etc via joins, and was just trying to avoid having another table. Regarding the name of the table, that's it primary function, to record the birthdays of family members. The relations and such are just add on info. I'll add the table for the relationships. Again, thanks for the info!